# how to get user's current country and protect it from manipulation?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, geolocation, location, geocoding

I'm developing Facebook app on iOS, Android and Web. I want to get user's current country and protect it from manipulation?

This function has to be practical across mobile app and web app. and can't be manipulate by the user(it has to show the real country they are currently in and they can not change it).

How can I do that?

Can I use Facebook App to get user Location? is it the real location or it is just a location the user has written on their profile?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, getting accurate geographic information can be done using a few techniques.

### GPS positioning

This is done on the user's device, therefore it can be faked and can't be trusted. For example, the Android official emulator allows the user to input arbitrary data for testing purposes.

### GeoIP

Assuming the user can connect to a server through an IP network, he will have an IP address. Then on the server-side, which you control, you can query one of the existing GeoIP databases to get an estimation of the user location from the IP address.

While you are the one looking up the country code, it can be faked for example through the use of a proxy server located in a different country.

### Device language/country

It is doable for example on Android via the use of the telephony API:

```
TelephonyManager manager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCode = manager.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

I'm not sure it is easily modifiable, however this is by no means a portable approach, especially for web applications.

In the later case, the `accept-language` HTTP request header can be used, since browsers usually advertise the user's favorite language. While not accurate, it can still give an estimation of the user's country in the case the language is unique to a country.
Just as every user-supplied information, it still can't be trusted though.

### Bottom line

There are very few guarantees that a user's geographic information is accurate, especially since the advent of country-protected multimedia contents represents an incentive for people to actively find solutions to circumvent such protections.